# Does Google Elevation show facilities elevations?

Tags: google-elevation-api

I can't get the answer anywhere so I put my question here, not technical one. I'm not Elevation user yet. Before that I would like to find out sth. If I would like to get the elevations for railroad from point A to B for the gropup of certain GPS's, will Elevation get me the elevations of ground or actual ones for tracks, including the heights of facilities e.g. bridges etc.?

Second option is preferable.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It returns just the terrain elevation not the height of the facilities.

Sources:

- https://groups.google.com/g/google-maps-js-api-v3/c/V0biFYWbHPg
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62757830?pli=1

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but the informations you provided seem to be quite old. Of course they might be accurate, but still.